# Only last image is loading from url in scrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, sdwebimage, uiscrollviewdelegate

In my iOS app I have have a lots of view and image and labels are the subviews of the. view. My problem is while loading images from url or remote server only last image is loading from url . Other images are loaded with placeholders. Tried many ways but unable to solve it . My code and screenshot are provided below

```
catScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width,300)];
catScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(([popularCategoryArray count] * 90)/1.8 + 10, catScrollView.frame.size.height);
[_parentScrollView addSubview:catScrollView];
catScrollView.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xE8F7FE);
catScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
catScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
catScrollView.delegate=self;


for(int i =0;i<[popularCategoryArray count];i++)
{
    Category* category=[popularCategoryArray objectAtIndex:i];
     UIView *catView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    if(i>=[popularCategoryArray count]/2+1)
    {

        catView.frame = CGRectMake(10 + y * 100, 4*10+90+10, 90, 120);



        y++;
    }
    else
    {
        catView.frame = CGRectMake(10 + x * 100, 10, 90, 120);

        x=i;


    }
    imageCat=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 90)];
    imageCat.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [imageCat sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:category.ImageURL]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_list"]];


    [catView addSubview:imageCat];




    UILabel *labelCat=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 95, catView.frame.size.width, 25)];
    labelCat.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    labelCat.text=category.BngTitle;
    labelCat.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    labelCat.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:12.0];
    [catView addSubview:labelCat];


    catView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];



    [catScrollView addSubview:catView];



}
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Category is this your array?

Comment: yes text and image url of category are loading from array

Comment: can you share which index contain image in that array ? or share one result please.

Comment: array contains NSObject data which I parse it  from Json. In the nsobject class catefory , catefory.imageUrl contains the image url and using the code 
[imageCat sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:category.ImageURL]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_list"]];
I am downloading the image and replace the placeholder image

Comment: can you share one result which contain in array?

Comment: Its better If i could provide screenshot in the comment 
33 categories are loaded in the array
<__NSArrayM 0x608000055030>(
<Category: 0x60000033f180>,
)
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString*   CategoryId;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString*   SubCategoryId;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString*   ImageURL;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString*   BngTitle;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169495/discussion-between-rb1509-and-mahboobiosdeveloper).

Comment: @MahboobiOSDeveloper Does `imageCat` is a property of your class?

Comment: Your code looks right, but we don't know what's going on with the `imageCat` variable before and after the loop. Try making it a local variable as in `UIImageView *imageCat = ...`. Also print out URLs with `NSLog("%@", category.ImageURL)` and check that they are correct and functional.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use `UICollectionView` which is exactly for that and allow memory management (only load visible cells)? If you have a lot of "cells", you could get a memory warning.

Comment: Also, could you use the other method of `SDWebImage`, the one with the completion handler and check if there is any error message there?

Comment: Why `imageCat` is global? It should be local variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that in `UIView+Webcache.m`'s `sd_internalSetImageWithURL` method, the following code is executed on every run through your loop.

```
NSString *validOperationKey = operationKey ?: NSStringFromClass([self class]);
[self sd_cancelImageLoadOperationWithKey:validOperationKey];
```

The `operationKey` is always the same because in your default invocation it is not set, so it's possed as nil, and when it's nill it's just the class name. SDWebImage has a very aggressive policy of cancelling all previous requests that way.

Some people believe it only does that for multiple requests of the same URL, but this code does not vary on URL so that may be a bug or not. Your best bet may be to call the `sd_internalSetImageWithURL` method and set your own `operationKey` (something with a number in it so that they're all different).